# Why does "(null)" want access to my Twitter accounts?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

Have anyone seen this message before, when accessing the official twitter app?

```
"(null)" would like access to twitter accounts
```

I have an iPod Touch with iOS 5, not jail-broken.

Is it a virus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter has been integrated into iOS 5. To view the authorized apps connected to your account, go to Settings > Twitter. Any app that has the ability to "tweet" will request access to your Twitter credentials (Safari, Photos, for example).

The error message you are seeing is a bug in the Twitter client. It should read: "*Twitter* would like access to twitter accounts." Allowing it access means not having to sign in using the client. Your credentials will be pulled right from iOS.

[image]

There are no viruses or exploits in the wild for any handheld Apple device. Furthermore, such exploits would require the installation of a unscrupulous app, something which Apple's App Store protects against.

You can read more about Apple's iOS Twitter integration [here](http://www.macstories.net/stories/ios-5-twitter-integration/).

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in the Twitter app, not a virus. `(null)` is simply what the program gets when trying to insert a nonexistent name into `would like access to Twitter accounts`.

I would report this as a bug to Twitter.